# ntpdate and firewall: no server suitable for synchronization found

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, ntpdate

I'm behind a firewall and only have access to ports 80 and port 443.

How can I sync my system's clock?

Here's the command I issue:

```
sudo ntpdate -u 1.debian.pool.ntp.org
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> no server suitable for synchronization found.

Is there some other program that can sync over port 80/443? Or is it possible to get ntpdate to work on these ports?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Why not change the firewall?

Answer (score 2):

No, ntpdate does not do that. I'm assuming that you're behind some sort of company firewall that you don't have mandate to access - if so, then it's likely that your organization does have some sort of internal time server that you should be able to use.

If, on the other hand, you can change the firewall, it's port 123 UDP you should be opening.

Comment: Just looking back on this question. Yes, there's a company firewall - I had to use ntp.mycompany.com.